# What happens when the response is not closed with Apache Connector in Jersey Client?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, apache-httpclient-4.x, jersey-2.0

I run a Java web service at my workplace which uses `JerseyClient` to make HTTP requests. A few weeks ago we switched the default connector implementation with [`ApacheConnector`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.19/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/apache/connector/ApacheConnectorProvider.html) and our server stopped handling requests after some time due to threads getting stuck. The issue was exactly same as described here - https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3772. We were running a pretty outdated version of Jersey - 2.19. We fixed the issue by using a higher version of Jersey where this bug was fixed. However, I am still curious as to why things broke and want to understand them better.

According to the conversation on the GitHub issue, the problem is due to a bug in Jersey code wherein `response.close()` is not called.

[This comment](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/pull/3861#discussion_r466634475) on the commit which fixes the issue says -

> 2 years down the line and because of a missing `response.close()` in previous versions of Jersey in a finally block, the pooled http connection was never released.
> Our leased http connections never were returned to the pool because response wasn't being explicitly read into entities in some cases.

I don't understand what this means. I want to understand how does this bug work. Why do threads get stuck? Why is it important to call `response.close()`. What does `response.close()` do? What scenarios does the bug surface in? (because my server did not die outright, it was fine for a few days then broke).

I was able to reproduce this issue when I artificially injected high latency in the calls made by Jersey (we have a tool at work which can intercept packets and hold them for a set amount of time, so the application perceives that as latency in the response of the call). Which led to a `javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException` with "Read timed out". Why did this experiment reproduce the issue?

Thanks!